# Create a printf function with custom prefix

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a printf function that print like this

```
[INFO] whatever 123
```

va_args works but I don't know how to add a prefix. At least the following code won't do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void myprintf (char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list argp;
  va_start (argp, fmt); 
  vfprintf (stdout, "[INFO] " fmt, argp); 
  va_end (argp);
}

int main (int argc , char **argv)
{
    myprintf ("arg count is %d\n", argc);
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same as this, and smashing my head against every single brick wall available on the way. I want to make `Log::WriteLine(_Format, ...)` just act as a straight pass-through for `printf`, but apend `\r\n` to the input string; `Log::DebugInfo(_Format, ...)` prepend `[Debug]` to the input string, and `Log::ServerInfo(_Format, ...)` prepend `[Server]` to the input string. But whenever I wrap the `printf` command like this, it loses its syntax highlighting and validation for `%s`, `%d`, etc. They're usually lime green, and tell me if I need to cast. I need that as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
"[INFO] " fmt
```

This code won't work. The "string pasting" behavior you're trying to use here is a preprocessor behavior, not a C operator. It can only be used on string constants -- not variables.

The easiest way of getting the behavior you want here will be to simply call `printf` twice:

```
printf("[INFO] ");
va_start(argp, fmt);
vfprintf(stdout, fmt, argp);
va_end(argp);
```

More difficult approaches which you may want to consider include:

- Define `myprintf()` as a macro instead of a function so that it can use string pasting on the format argument.
- Copy `"[INFO] "` and `fmt` into a temporary buffer and use that as a formatting string.
- Copy `"[INFO] "` into a temporary buffer, use `vsnprintf()` to append the output to the buffer, then output that.

Comment: Though the macro technique would mean you can't pass through a format from some other function, use a common `static const char special_fmt[] = "...";` in multiple calls, etc. So I'd probably avoid that one.